# Retrieving cookies from a Steam OAuth login site

Tags: python, cookies, steam

Trying to grab cookies from http://www.tf2outpost.com

In order to get the necessary cookie (it's called `uhash`), one must be logged on with their Steam OAuth + getting past the dual factor authentication.

My current method of getting cookie is first logging in on my browser, go to the Chrome's Dev Tools, and going to the Network tab to grab the `uhash` cookie. Since I want to automate everything, this is obviously not the valid solution.

My question is - how do I, using Python, programmatically capture my cookies if the site requires me to log in?